# Windows 8.1-virus at user sign in screen

Tags: windows-8, virus, anti-virus, eset

Running Windows 8.1 on my new Lenovo laptop, with ESET Smart Security installed.   When I first turned on my computer, in addition to the usual profile name of my laptop computer, two new unidentified user profile names appeared before my login screen.   The names below each profile box are gibberish.  I stupidly clicked on one of the boxes. I immediately got a message on my screen, "Hi" then it showed "Setting things up for you..."

I turned the computer off immediately using the power button.  I restarted the computer holding down the shift key.   The windows utility screen came up and under advanced options I chose to restart the computer to get to the safemode screen. When the computer restarted it repeated the "Hi" message.  I immediately powered down the computer.  What is happening, and what should I do now?

Comment: The user login screen is a protected feature of Windows.  Its very unlikely a virus has been able to insert itself at that stage, while everything is possible, a virus at that log-in stage isn't possible.

Comment: Have you enabled Anti-Theft mode? This feature creates a "ghost" user in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

A virus is indeed unlikely.
The profiles may have been created by various services (including something like ESS), but they should not appear at the login screen. The 'hi' thing appeared because you tried to login with one of those users and practically W8 was creating the profile sub-components at that point.

You should run a repair of the OS and then after logging in with your username check out what's with the other user profiles and delete them if necessary (directly from C:\Users).